# Where can I find details about necessary system accuracy, integrity etc of a conventional navigation aid?

Tags: regulations, radio-navigation, non-precision-approach, precision-approach

I am wondering where (probably in which ICAO document) can I find information about the required accuracy, integrity etc. for a conventional navigation aid for non-precision and precision approaches (required vertical and horizontal accuracy, etc.) I found that GNSS information can be find in ICAO Annex 10 Volume 1, but I coulnd't find similar clear information about conventional navigation aids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These details can also be found in **ICAO Annex 10 - Volume 1 Radio Navigation Aids**. This is from the table of contents of the [Seventh Edition (from 2018)](https://www.bazl.admin.ch/dam/bazl/de/dokumente/Fachleute/Regulationen_und_Grundlagen/icao-annex/icao_annex_10_aeronauticaltelecommunicationsvolumei-radionavigat.pdf.download.pdf/icao_annex_10_aeronauticaltelecommunicationsvolumei-radionavigat.pdf):

> CHAPTER 1. Definitions
>
> CHAPTER 2. General provisions for radio navigation aids
>
> 2.1 Standard radio navigation aids
> 2.2 Ground and flight testing
> 2.3 Provision of information on the operational status of radio navigation services
> 2.4 Power supply for radio navigation aids and communication systems
> 2.5 Human Factors considerations
>
> CHAPTER 3. Specifications for radio navigation aids
>
> 3.1 Specification for ILS
> 3.2 Specification for precision approach radar system
> 3.3 Specification for VHF omnidirectional radio range (VOR)
> 3.4 Specification for non-directional radio beacon (NDB)
> 3.5 Specification for UHF distance measuring equipment (DME)
> 3.6 Specification for en-route VHF marker beacons (75 MHz)
> 3.7 Requirements for the Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS)
> 3.8 [Reserved]
> 3.9 System characteristics of airborne ADF receiving systems
> 3.10 [Reserved]
> 3.11 Microwave landing system (MLS) characteristics